# CakePHP Convention name or smth connected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, model

I have an issue with cakephp name conventions but i can't find my mistake here.

I Have two models, and they're joined ( i will include code later), in index file i have problem to display data from two different tables. The Error occures.

> Database Error
>   Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Com.info_id' in 'field list'

Models

(Info.php)

```
<?php

class Info extends AppModel
{
public $hasMany = array('Com');
public $validate = array(
    'title'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty'
    ),
    'body'=>array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty'
    )
);
}
?>
```

(Com.php)

```
<?php

class Com extends AppModel
{
public $belongsTo = array('Info');
public $validate = array(
    'mail'=>array(
        'requierd'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),
            'message'=>'Write your email'
        )
    ),
    'body'=>array(
        'required'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),
            'messages'=>'Write smth'
        )
    )
);
}
?>
```

Controllers
(InfosController.php)

```
<?php

class InfosController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
public $components = array('Session');

public function index()
{
    $this->Info->recursive = 1;
    $this->set('inform', $this->Info->find('all'));
}}
```

(ComsController.php) ( i triend even remove index from this, doesn't work)

```
<?php
class ComsController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
public $components = array('Session');

public function index()
{
    $this->set('com',  $this->Infos_com->find('all'));
}}
```

and at least (View/Infos/index.ctp) ( it's not important, becouse, index even if is empty, the error still occur), body part

```
 <?php if (isset($inform)) {
foreach($inform as $info) {
        echo $info['Info']['title']; echo '<br>';
        echo $info['Info']['body'];
        foreach($info['Com'] as $comment) {
            echo $comment['Com']['body'];
        }
    }
} ?>
```

tables in my db are Infos and Coms. I work befor only on Info table and i haven't any problem, **problem starts when i use $public $hasMany = array('Com')**

i will be gratefull for any tip or advice.
Best Regards !!

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but do you have a column named "info_id" in your "Col" table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the Cake manual for the conventions.  Depending on how you relate one table to another it expects a foreign key of the form `relatedtable_id` in one table to relate to the other: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html.

Also, as @thecodeparadox points out, `Infos_com` is not a valid model.  That convention would be for a model that represents a join table between `Info` and `Com` that held foreign keys for both tables.  I strongly suggest you use the `bake` utility after making sure your DB is setup to convention: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have a `info_id` in your `Com` table.
2. Here 
   `$this->Infos_com->find('all')`, `Infos_com` is not a valid model name.